# Vector norm for a matrix

Tags: matrices, vectors

$$
‖x‖_w^2=x^H Wx
$$
How do I calculate the vector norm of that equation? If I am given x how do I figure out the weighting matrix W and compute the vector norm?

Comment: You need to be given the weighting matrix $W$ (and a vector $x$) in order to compute $\|x\|_W$.

Comment: Note: this will be a norm if and only if the weighting matrix $W$ is positive definite.

Comment: You would need to be given some amount of information if you really have to "figure out the weighting matrix".  What information are you given, exactly?

Comment: We are trying to figure out if this norm corresponds to 1-norm, 2-norm, or inf-norm. The definitions for those norms to what I have found online do not resemble this vector norm. I am not given a matrix but from previous questions I can compare the output of this vector to the norms mentioned above (we were given the hilbert matrix previously although I am not entirely sure I am on the correct path but I wanted to give it a try. Does this make it a bit more clear? Because I am lost with this.

Comment: *"We are trying to figure out if this norm corresponds to 1-norm, 2-norm, or inf-norm"*. What do you mean by "correspond" here?  If $W$ is the identity matrix, then this is just the $2$-norm

Comment: If it resembles it. So only if the case of W being the identity matrix the vector resembles the 2-norm?

Comment: What do you mean by "resemble"? I'd say that the $1$-norm resembles the $2$-norm in that they're both norms.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Anyway, I said that if $W$ is the identity matrix, then $\|\cdot\|_W$ is *precisely* the $2$-norm.  The two norms are *identical*.  In other cases, I might say that $\|\cdot\|_W$ resembles the $2$-norm, but that depends on what you mean by "resemble".

Comment: This is a norm iff $W$ is HPD and is related to the 2-norm. If $W=Y^*Y$, then $\|x\|_W^2=x^*Y^*Yx=\|Yx\|_2^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your help and the question uses resembles so I cannot be more specific than what was asked of me. But I think your answer is sufficient for me to move on. Thanks you again.